How to turn name into verb (inventing it in effect)
I've just watched a funny interview with President Camacho, the main character in the film Idiocracy, who has travelled back in time to run for the White House in 2024.
Je viens de regarder une interview rigolote donnée par President Camacho, le personnage principal du film Idiocracy, qui a voyagé dans le temps pour se présenter à l'élection présidentielle américaine en 2024.
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_RgG1Ayf4kI
The interviewer asks, "What would your first action be as president?" The wrestler answers, "I would Will Smith half of Congress."
L'intervieweur lui demande, "Quelle serait la première mesure que vous prendriez en tant que président?" Le catcheur répond, "Je Will Smith-erais la moitié des députés au congrès."
If you aren't aware, Will Smith became infamous in the 2022 Oscars for slapping Chris Rock.
Si vous n'êtes pas au courant, Will Smith est devenu notoire à la cérémonie des Oscars en 2022 en donnant une claque à Chris Rock.
Is there any way in French to turn a name of a guy into a verb?
Est-il permis en français de transformer en verbe le nom d'une personne ? Certes, on peut dire "Je les giflerais tous à l'instar de Will Smith". Mais le style cool de Camacho fait partie du personnage. Dire "I would Will Smith them", avec autant de brièveté, c'est beaucoup plus cool.

Complètement hors-sujet: Idiocracy n'est pas un "film", mais un documentaire...

@Frank Not a film? It's fiction, it's a sci-fi movie. And anyway, documentaries are also films, they're just not fiction.

@None (Hors-sujet) oui oui, c'était ironique.

@Frank J'avais pas compris l'ironie !

The generation of verbs from proper names is a well established tradition in French. Machiavéliser is the 1st example that comes to mind. Like almost all verb neologisms, they have 1st group conjugations.

Bonne question au subject de verbalisation des noms mais ce documentaire (d'acc avec @Frank) ce n'est qu'un bon exemple qui cherche à employer une traduction grammaticale. Ça n'a rien a voir avec ce qui s'est vraiment passé entre Smith et Rock 20 après le film Idiocracy.  C'est un bon exemple de fiction spéculative, de la littérature qui décrit ce qui nous est déjà un peu arrivé, et +1 pour l'exemple d'un nom propre/nom de famille qui se transforme en verbe.

Le procédé est tout à fait courant et on le trouve fréquemment dans le jargon politique.
Un verbe qu'on entend souvent depuis environ une dizaine d'années c'est macroniser. Je ne sais pas si on le trouve déjà dans les dictionnaires papier (je n'en ai pas de récent sous la main) mais il a son entrée dans le  wiktionnaire avec trois exemples. Et on en trouve facilement d'autres.
Un article de 2018 dans Le Monde :

D’où ce souci, de ma part, de ne pas « macroniser Ricœur » et de ne pas « ricœuriser Macron ».

Un tweet de 2017 de Bernard Pivot :

Se macroniser. Déf.: se rallier au futur gagnant. Ex.: début 44, pétainistes et indécis se macronisaient pour de Gaulle.

Et pour élargir l'éventail politique on peut citer aussi :

mélanchoniser :


Et si au lieu de mélanchoniser les orateurs, on mélanchonisait les participants aux réunions ? (Sur un blog)


lepéniser:


Même lepénisé, le pays devra continuer de rembourser cette dette. — (Jean-Luc Porquet, Le vieux programme du FN marine dans l’eau de rose, dans Le Canard enchaîné, 15 février 2017, page 4) (Example sentence from the wiktionnaire entry)

Et bien sûr le procédé peut se faire avec des noms propres qui ne sont pas d'origine française :

D’un autre côté, les Conservateurs qui ont quitté Boris Johnson perdront l’investiture du parti qui va, ainsi, se « johnsoniser ». (Atlantico, 4/11/2019).


La France est-elle en train de se trumpiser ? (France-Inter, 27/07/2021)

Poutiniser in the wiktionnaire.
Donc la traduction « Je Will Smitherais la moitié des députés au congrès. » est conforme à la tradition française de création de nouveaux verbe en -er (1er groupe). Personnellement je l'écrirais en un seul mot et sans majuscule initiale : willsmitherais.

« Jordan Bardella va-t-il se “méloniser”, et est-il “mélonisable” ? », se demandait un grand banquier de la place de Paris. (Le Monde, 08/07/2024)


Sans lien, mais «poutiniser» serait tellement mieux si c’était culinaire… ;-)

@PierrePaquette Evidemment... :-)

@PierrePaquette ça peut difficilement être culinaire. Alimentaire tout au plus, soit dit en toute méchanceté. Comme dans Cuisiner la poutine est à cuisiner ce que la justice militaire est à la justice.

@FrançoisJurain: Il n’y a pas de méchanceté là-dedans. Je serais plus du genre à mourir de faim qu’à manger de la poutine! ;-)

La réponse principale me semble excellente mais j'ajouterais que l'on peut, dans certains cas, également parler de "faire une (nom de la personne)".
Par exemple, faire une Shy'm a été très utilisé après le gadin monumental de la chanteuse Shy'm pendant un de ses concerts.
En revanche, je ne sais pas exactement à quoi se réfère "une" dans cette expression. Peut-être une bévue ?

Dans « faire une Shy'm » une réfère à chute (une chute comme celle de Shy'm). Mais ceci ne répond pas vraiment à la question qui porte sur la création d'un verbe, et pas une périphrase.
